# How to preserve Gradle task "up-to-dateness" when its output is modified by a finalizing task?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, aspectj

A legacy project uses AspectJ to directly modify the output of the Java compiler. In a Gradle script the 'compileJava' task is the one that invokes that compiler and is very much tied into a network of dependencies of other tasks and general flow of those dependencies (say 'jar' task and its output especially).

To leverage that and avoid duplicating pretty much everything in a large multi-project setup, we run AspectJ weaving on the very output of `compileJava` so that downstream tasks (such as 'jar') pick it up without additional configuration. This is presently done as an extra doLast {} step added to the `compileJava` task. Using doLast makes the `compileJava` task never up-to-date on its own but there is also the fact that it modifies the actual "outputs" of compileJava so this may be detected as "NON-up-to-dateness" of compileJava as well (inputs didn't change but outputs did).

We tried separating the AspectJ weaving into a dedicated finalizing task (compileJava.finalizedBy aspectJ; aspectJ.dependsOn compileJava). That avoids the doLast {} modification on the compileJava task but leaves the other challenge and brings a new one - what are the inputs for the new aspectJ task?

If we configure the "truth", that is that inputs = outputs = outputs of compileJava, then the task will never be up-to-date as it changes its own inputs. If we cheat and try something like the following:

```
task aspectJ {
    dependsOn compileJava
    inputs.files compileJava.inputs.files
    ...
```

... then we address that but risk issues with incomplete compilations perhaps (less important) and we still have the problem of "confusing" compileJava task as we modified its outputs, so next time it may re-run.

I looked at other possibilities, such as trying to always and only run aspectJ if compileJava runs but could not find a way to do it (no answer for that):

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/execute-task-onlyif-other-task-will-execute/5794

Yes, I know that a clean/proper solution would be to clearly distinguish between inputs and outputs but that is *far* from trivial here and introduces a ton of unwanted complexity everywhere else.

Anything I am / we are missing? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for being unable to help with Gradle. If Maven is an option, I let me know. I know how to use AspectJ Maven Plugin in different constellations.

Comment: Thank you, but no, thank you. I abandoned Maven years ago as it, for the kinds of projects I work on, causes many more problems than it solves.

Comment: Then thin with Gradle is that there are several fragmentary AspectJ plugins but obviously no (de facto) standard one on eye level with AspectJ Maven. Maybe someone should port that one to Gradle in order to avoid most people using their own home-brew recipes for AspectJ compilation. So I wish you good luck with solving your problem and can only encourage you to publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem on GitHub in order to attract Gradle experts who are able to help you. :-) I am an AspectJ expert and quite versed with Maven, but Gradle is not my world.

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of "too much choice, none perfect" w.r.t. AspectJ in Gradle. I can change this but presently we use the Ant task (from Gradle) to do this. AspectJ is not an issue here in itself. The setup in Gradle works as well but unnecessarily runs things which take extra seconds and cause some additional side effects. If "up-to-date" worked this would be fine.